# split a file path into its constituent paths in Hive/Presto

Tags: string, split, hive, hiveql, presto

Using Presto/Hive, I'd like to split a string in the following way.

Input string:

```
\Users\Killer\Downloads\Temp
\Users\Killer\Downloads\welcome
```

and have the query return these rows:

```
\Users\
\Users\Killer\
\Users\Killer\Downloads\
\Users\Killer\Downloads\Temp
\Users\
\Users\Killer\
\Users\Killer\Downloads\
\Users\Killer\Downloads\welcome
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: You surely need [`UNNEST`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) with some addition of [array functions](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) & [string functions](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/string.html). What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can do the job:

```
SELECT item, array_join( array_agg(item) over (order by id), '\' )
FROM UNNEST(split('\Users\Killer\Downloads\Temp','\')) WITH ORDINALITY t(item,id)
```

**Explanation:**

We first `split` the sting to an array by the delimeter `\`, then we `UNNEST` this array into rows, one row per item. After that we do `array_agg` on all items till this row id ("rolling" aggregation of window function), and finally we `array_join` them back with the `\` delimeter.

Comment: I am running the following query, but the results are going into a loop forever I am dealing with millions of records   
                                                                                                                                   
SELECT fsiamge.id, array_join(array_agg(item) over (order by id,level),'/')
FROM fsiamge 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(split(id,'/')) WITH ORDINALITY t(item,level);

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Hive. split to get array, explode array using posexplode, collect array again using analytic function and concatenate (literals `\` should be shielded with one more backslash - `\\` and in the regex used in split, single backslash represented as four backslashes):

```
select s.level, 
        concat(concat_ws('\\',collect_set(s.path) over(order by level rows between unbounded preceding and current row)),
              case when level<size(split(t.str,'\\\\'))-1  then '\\' else '' end 
             ) result
  from mytable t lateral view posexplode(split(t.str,'\\\\')) s as level, path
```

Result:

```
level   result
0         \
1         \Users\
2         \Users\Killer\
3         \Users\Killer\Downloads\
4         \Users\Killer\Downloads\Temp
```